# XPathNavigator with xpath gives wrong node back

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xpathnavigator

I try to get some specific values from an xml config. See example below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ExcelConfig>
    <ExcelDocument name="Customer" type="flat">
        <IdentityColumn>
            <Column name="Id" />
        </IdentityColumn>
        <Validate>
            <Column name="Name" mandatory="true" />
            <Column name="FirstName" mandatory="true" />
            <OrColumns mandatory="true">
                <Column name="PostalCode" mandatory="false" />
                <Column name="PostalCode2" mandatory="false" />
            </OrColumns>
        </Validate>
    </ExcelDocument>
    <ExcelDocument name="Company" type="flat">
        <IdentityColumn>
            <Column name="Id" />
        </IdentityColumn>
        <Validate>
            <Column name="Name" mandatory="true" />
            <Column name="FirstName" mandatory="true" />
            <OrColumns mandatory="true">
                <Column name="PostalCode" mandatory="false" />
                <Column name="PostalCode2" mandatory="false" />
            </OrColumns>
        </Validate>
    </ExcelDocument>
    <ExcelDocument name="SomeOtherType" type="block">
        <IdentityBlock>
            <Column name="Period" col="A" />
            <Column name="Period2" col="B" />
        </IdentityBlock>
        <Validate>
            <Column name="Name" mandatory="true" />
            <Column name="FirstName" mandatory="true" />
        </Validate>
    </ExcelDocument>
</ExcelConfig>
```

I use the following code to get some information from the excel file. 
"ValidationConfiguration" is the string with the previous configuration.

```
            //Get Different NodeTypes of Excel documents
            List<XPathNavigator> types = XmlHelper.GetNodeTypes(validationConfiguration, "/ExcelConfig/ExcelDocument");
            List<XPathNavigator> flatTypes = XmlHelper.GetNodeTypes(validationConfiguration,
                                                                     "//ExcelConfig/ExcelDocument[@type='flat']");
            List<XPathNavigator> blockTypes = XmlHelper.GetNodeTypes(validationConfiguration,
                                                                     "//ExcelConfig/ExcelDocument[@type='block']");


            //First we check if the file is from the flat type and get the IdentityColumns
            List<XPathNavigator> identityColumnsNode = XmlHelper.GetNodeTypes(validationConfiguration, "//ExcelConfig/ExcelDocument[@type='flat']/IdentityColumn");
```

You can find the XmlHelper class below.

```
 public static class XmlHelper
    {
        public static List<XPathNavigator> GetNodeTypes(string xmlConfiguration,string xPath)
        {
            XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(new StringReader(xmlConfiguration));
            XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();

            XPathExpression expr = nav.Compile(xPath);
            List<XPathNavigator> elements = new List<XPathNavigator>();

            foreach (XPathNavigator node in nav.Select(expr))
            {
                elements.Add(node);   
            }

            return elements;
        }

        public static List<string> GetIdentityColumnNames(List<XPathNavigator> xPathNavigators)
        {
            List<string> identityColumns = new List<string>();

            foreach (XPathNavigator xPathNavigator in xPathNavigators)
            {
                foreach (XPathNavigator test in xPathNavigator.Select("//Column"))
                {
                    identityColumns.Add(test.GetAttribute("name", ""));
                }
            }

            return identityColumns;
        }
    }
```

Now i want to do the following. I selected the identityColumnsNodes(they contains the IdentityColumn from the exceldocuments that have the flat type).
The i get for al that types the colums. But when i try that, i get all columns back from the whole file. He don't only the items from the node that i use.

```
 foreach (XPathNavigator identityColumNode in identityColumnsNode)
                        {
                            List<string> identityColumns = XmlHelper.GetIdentityColumnNames(identityColumnsNode);          
                        }
```

The second problem/thing i want to do --> the best way to select the right validate node from the specific file. With the identityColumns (that i get back and my list of HeaderRow Cells i know what file it is.  But how can i select that validate node?

Or are their better methods to do this stuff?